# Use data from a JSON result into a table

Tags: php, ajax, json

Sorry for the bad titling, I had difficulty naming it.

I am trying to take this data:

```
<?php

require '../lib/config.php';

// Get the server statuses
$pdb = connectPDO();
$stmt = $pdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM serverlist');
$stmt->execute();
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Which gives this result:
http://ichris.xyz/ajax/server-status.ajax.php

and then take that data and insert it into a table
http://ichris.xyz/server_list.php (the table I have made to insert this data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$.get('ajax/server-status.ajax.php').done(function(results) {
        var statusList = $.parseJSON(results);
        var tableBody = $("table tbody");
        if ($.isArray(statusList)){
            for(var index in statusList){
                var status = statusList[index];
                $("<tr>").append("<td>"+status["name"]+"</td>")
                   .append("<td>"+status["faction2_name"]+"</td>")
                   .append("<td>"+status["map"]+"</td>")
                   .append("<td>"+status["players_online"]+"/"+status["players_max"]+"</td>")
                   .append("<td>"+(status["has_password"] ? 'Yes' : 'No')+"</td>")
                .appendTo( tableBody );
            }
        }
    });
```

See it in action in a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h62d25n1/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON DECODE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Once you serialize the json feed, then using a while or for loop run your inserts using php.